# Rewire: How is it possible for this function to execute without returning the specified return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, eval

I am using the [Rewire package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to inject mocks in connection with doing unit testing. I was hoping to be able to test private functions in my modules:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

function adder (){ //not exported
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    return a + b;
};
```

by doing this:

```
var rewire = require('rewire'),
    md = rewire('./module'),
    mock = {a: 30, b: 40},
    cb = md.__get__('adder');

console.log(md.__with__(mock)(cb));
```

which logs the following to the console:

```
30
40
undefined
```

I find this strange because the logging of the `30` and `40` seems to indicate that `adder()` has successfully been invoked with the `mock`.

But why is the return value `undefined` in stead of `70`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that the callback function returned by rewire does not return a value unless it's a promise (in which case it returns the promise).

`md.__with__(mock)` returns a function that takes a callback, so it can be boiled down to something like this: `function(callback){ callback(); }`

and because that function returned by `__with__()` does not return the result of the callback, you end up with undefined in your console log. In other words, you're logging the result of the function returned by the mock instead of the return value of the callback passed to the mock.

Edit...Try this as proof:

```
md.__with__(mock)(function(){ console.log(cb());});
```

Here we'll be logging the value of the return value of cb (adder) instead of the undefined return from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of a callback will be `promise`:

```
// https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/blob/master/lib/__with__.js#L29
returned = callback();
isPromise = returned && typeof returned.then === "function";
if (isPromise) {
    returned.then(undo, undo);
    return returned;
}
```